# orientationchange event fires scroll & resize event

Tags: jquery, mobile, orientation, mobile-safari

For a project I'm working on, I ran into a strange issue, for which I could not find an answer on here (or anywhere else).

I tried creating a Fiddle to demonstrate what happens, but due to the nature of my script, and the way jsfiddle functions, it is not working correctly. Anyway, [here's a link to the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c_kick/Wcnef/) so at least you'll have the code.

**What I want to happen**

Execute a single handler (`onViewportChange`) on three possible `window` events: `resize`, `orientationchange` and `scroll`. Based on the event type, the handler will figure out what to do. Sounds pretty straightforward.

**What I did**

For this example, I have limited the handler to echo the event type, for testing purposes:

```
var onViewportChange = function(e) {
    alert(e.type);
};
```

I bind the handler to the events: (I have also tried `.bind()` with an array of events, and several separate binds)

```
$(window).on({
    'orientationchange resize scroll' : function(e){
        onViewportChange(e);
    }
});
```

The HTML is completely empty, except for the arbitrary base elements (doctype, html, body and ofcourse jquery and this script)

**What actually happens**

And now it gets weird: the events fire fine on desktop browsers (mainly due to the lack of an orientationchange event firing), but not on mobile devices (tested on an iOS6+ iPad 3rd generation and an iOS6+ iPhone 5). When I rotate my the device(s);

- The iPad and iPhone fire all three: `orientationchange`, `resize` followed by `scroll`
- Chrome on the iPhone fires `resize` followed by `orientationchange`
- An Android phone I borrowed triggers `orientationchange` followed by `resize`

(Note that the order of events may not be accurate because of race conditions.)

And here's why I linked it to the `orientationchange` event: When I remove the `orientationchange` event (leaving `resize` and `scroll`), only the `scroll` event is fired on a device rotation, but no longer the `resize` event.

I don't understand why all events fire at once. At least; I can imagine that a `resize` is triggered on an `orientationchange` because the window dimensions change, but a `scroll`?

Does anyone know why this is happening?

**edit** I've set up a demo here: http://beta.hnldesign.nl/orientation/index.html

Comment: Apparently Mobile Safari triggers the `resize` event when the `window.scrollTop` and `window.scrollLeft` values are reconstucted/reevaluated internally. You can use a flag to avoid triggering of the `scroll` event as a workaround.

Comment: I imagine that a `scroll` event is being fired because Safari tries to scroll the user to the point they were at on the page before the orientation was changed...

Comment: Thanks inhan, but how will I differentiate between a reevaluation of 'scroll' and an actual user 'scroll'?

Comment: Can you set a flag on `orientationchange` (with a short timeout for resetting the flag) and check that when a `scroll` event is called? Or can you not guarantee that `orientationchange` will always be called before `scroll`?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't guarantee that. The trouble is that orientationchange and the scroll event conflict due to race conditions; whichever one fires first gets the cake. It's troubling, this

Answer (score 4):

Hmmmm, try this (extracted from jQuery API docs...) http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$(window).on({
  orientationchange: function(e) {
    onViewportChange(e);
  }, resize: function(e) {
    onViewportChange(e);
  }, scroll: function(e) {
    onViewportChange(e);
  }
});
```

This should work... maybe you need to tweak the code a little bit more